# Largest Ethereum Transactions

Tags: transactions, gas, database

Does anyone know of a database of large Ethereum transactions (in terms of Gas)? I am looking for large transactions on the testnet (Ropsten) or mainnet for analysis, ideally in the hundreds of thousands of Gas, or millions.

My alternative is to run a program to do this through Geth. But this will take time. In the case that someone has already done this, I would like to know!

Thanks

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen anything like it, ethgasstation.info was my first stop. If you're interested in a single example of a transaction with 1.5 Mgas, you can check this out: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9fea8a434bdfeccdec7ecd39973bf91724558de4758bb5dd5589eba7ce78db38